# Custom NavigationDrawer icon does not show on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-drawable

I have a custom icon for my `NavigationDrawer`, which I use like this:

```
new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.menu, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```

`R.drawable.menu` is my custom icon. This works perfectly when I test it on my Nexus 7 and I generate the drawables using this website: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

I have not tested it on any other device yet, but this seems really odd to me. What can cause this problem? If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `RelativeLayout` which I used as a custom `ActionBar` so I could fully customize it. It seems that in this case the `NavigationDrawer` icon does not show up at all. Most probably this is because of Samsung's custom skin. However, on Nexus 7 it worked just fine. I'm now using the default action bar and the icon show up again.